# How do I use AuthToken to get Adsense management Account Information?

Tags: android, google-api

Somehow I managed to get AuthToken from Google in android but now I can't find that how could I use this token to connect with the Adsense management Service to get my Adsense account information.???

Please provide some example. I searched everywhere but cant find any example related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct your AdsenseApiClient in java, it takes three arguments - a transport, a jsonFactory, and a transportInitializer.

The initializer has the magic you're looking for; specifically, there's a GoogleAccessProtectedResource which is a type of transport initializer that takes an accessToken as an argument.

```
GoogleAccessProtectedResource transportInitializer = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(authToken);
return ew AdsenseApiClient(transport, jsonFactory, transportInitializer);
```

My code, which is slightly more elaborate, looks like the following:

```
  private ApiClient createClientForAccessToken(
      final JsonHttpParser parser, HttpTransport transport, final String accessToken) {
    final AccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource = 
        new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(accessToken);
    HttpRequestInitializer transportInitializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() {
      @Override
      public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
        request.addParser(parser);
        request.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
        request.setReadTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
        request.setEnableGZipContent(true);
        request.setNumberOfRetries(0);
        accessProtectedResource.initialize(request);
      }
    };
    return new AdsenseApiClient(transport, parser.getJsonFactory(), transportInitializer);
  }
```

Comment: Exactly what happened i can't understand. How to create AdsenseAPiClient. it require some special library? Because i already import all apis client libraries. So let me know its class created by you? or it class librairy? N if it is created by u den hws it work? 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Api Java Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs) page has a number of samples including
[Task sample for Andriod](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html) specifically [TasksSample.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java?repo=samples) which gives examples of how to authenticate using the Google Api and OAuth2. For authentication this will be identical to how you should use the AdSense Management Api.